# Non-escaping parameter vs implicit capture of self error

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift3

I have a simplified struct that does the following:

1. Calls a function to checks the user's authorization status for access to their contacts. The function's completion handler returns `true` or `false`.
2. Within said function, if the status is not determined, it requests access to the contacts and returns either true or false for the  function's completion handler.
3. When the completion handler is returned, the value is used to determine whether to modify a property on the struct.

Here is the code:

```
// import Contacts

struct Foo {

    var allowedAccess: Bool

    mutating func doSomething() {
        checkStatus(complete: { success in
            if success {
                allowedAccess = true
            }
        })
    }

    private func checkStatus(complete: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

        if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .notDetermined {
            CNContactStore().requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { success, error in
                return success ? complete(true) : complete(false)
            })
        } else {
            complete(false)
        }
    }
}
```

The above code throws an error in `requestAccess` on:

```
 return success ? complete(true) : complete(false)
```

> Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'complete' may allow it to escape

Ok fine, so I add `@escaping`:

```
// Identical code above
private func checkStatus(complete: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
// Identical code above
```

Now it throws an error in `doSomething` on:

```
allowedAccess = true
```

> Closure cannot implicitly capture a mutating self parameter

It's either one error or the other. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Use a class,  not a struct

Comment: Why would this work? Is it because classes don't have do deal with anything mutating?

Comment: That's right. Class instances are reference types, not value types.